# Mac keyboard shortcut to focus the main HTML document/window in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

I use the keyboard to navigate webpages, but sometimes the focus will be on some element on the webpage that the keyboard will not respond to mouse down and space bar presses.

Is there a global shortcut to bring the focus back to the main window/HTML element so that key presses such as space and direction arrows will work?

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution?

Comment: @RangiRobinson I've been using a workaround. I focus the address bar with CMD+L. Then I just type `u` and press 'Enter', which unfocuses the search engine and focuses the HTML document. The reason `u` does this for me is because I added `u` as a Search Engine in Chrome settings with the query URL value of `javascript:`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the focus should shift to the next element in the webpage. In most cases you should be able to regain control of the space and direction keys.

If this can help you, here is the [full list](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165450?hl=en) of keyboard shortcuts in Chrome for Mac.

Comment: Thanks @pietrodn, but this doesn't reliably solve the problem. Many times I'll press Tab and the focus will go to another element that also takes over control of space bar and other keys.